# Yii permissions define to role

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, rbac

I was looking for an extension in yii which has dynamic permission assigned to roles.where each and every permission for a role can be able to view,delete and update their permissions individually.No sources for this yet.can anyone help thanks!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two popular Yii extensions :[Yii-user](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/) and [Yii rights](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights). You need to integrate these two extensions to have full access control management. You can use this wiki for learning how to work with them:

[Installing Yii Users and Rights to Newly Created Yii application](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/423/installing-yii-users-and-rights-to-newly-created-yii-app/)

Comment: Thanks :) but yii rights is showing installation error how to resolve it

Comment: i follwed same steps in the documentation..but still m getting this error..An error occured while installing rights

Comment: Yii rights installer is not working shows an error occured while installing rights.can anyone solve ???